# how to change the output that's returned from .sql File - plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following code:

```
DO $$
BEGIN   
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS widget_changes (
            change_id integer NOT NULL,
            change_date date NOT NULL default CURRENT_DATE,
            change_file character varying(255),
            description character varying(255)
        );


        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM pg_class where relname = 'widget_changes_change_id_seq' )
        THEN
            CREATE SEQUENCE widget_changes_change_id_seq
                START WITH 1
                INCREMENT BY 1
                NO MINVALUE
                NO MAXVALUE
                CACHE 1
                USING local;
                ALTER TABLE ONLY widget_changes ALTER COLUMN change_id SET DEFAULT nextval('widget_changes_change_id_seq'::regclass);
                INSERT INTO widget_changes VALUES (DEFAULT,DEFAULT, 'test.sql', 'test description');

        END IF;

END
$$
```

I would like to change this code so that when it's successful, it return OK.  If there are any failures, I want "FALSE" or some other single word.

Right now when I run from the command line, the first time through, it returns:

```
testbox:/tmp/ss# psql -U postgres -d widgets -f test.sql
DO
```

And then when I run it again, it returns:

```
psql:test.sql:26: NOTICE:  relation "widget_changes" already exists, skipping
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS widget_changes (
            change_id integer NOT NULL,
            change_date date NOT NULL default CURRENT_DATE,
            change_file character varying(255),
            description character varying(255)
        )"

PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 3 at SQL statement
DO
```

It looks like it's successfully testing for the "EXISTS" conditions, but I need to prevent all the verbosity and just return an OK / FAIL type thing. 
Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because the DO statement can only return void, so I think you need to create end execute a temporary function which returns text:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function create_table() RETURNS TEXT AS $$
DECLARE output TEXT;
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (select 1 from pg_tables where tablename = 'widget_changes') THEN
    CREATE TABLE widget_changes (
            change_id SERIAL NOT NULL,
            change_date date NOT NULL default CURRENT_DATE,
            change_file character varying(255),
            description character varying(255)
        );
    output = 'OK';    
  ELSE
    output = 'FALSE'; 
  END IF;
  INSERT INTO widget_changes VALUES (DEFAULT,DEFAULT, 'test.sql', 'test description');
  RETURN output;
END
$$ language plpgsql;

SELECT create_table();
DROP FUNCTION create_table();
```

In order to eliminate verbosity you need the psql options `--tuples-only` and `--quiet`. For easier parsing of the output, you can also use --no-align:

```
psql -d widgets --quiet --no-align --tuples-only -f test.sql
```

Short version:

```
psql -d widgets -qAt -f test.sql
```

PS: you don't need to create explicitly the sequence. The sequence is created automatically using the type [SERIAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)